# Responsive CSS not loading?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a separate CSS file so that when my website is loaded onto a smartphone, it's responsive.

I've called on both the global stylesheet and the mobile one in my HTML;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 480px)"
```

And I've put the following code at the top of the mobile stylesheet;

```
/* Smartphones ----------- */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

I've then copied the same css from the global stylesheet and made a few changes to test but none of the changes I make are loaded when I test it.

Am I missing anything? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think `handheld` is supported by anything anymore to be honest. Just detect device width

Comment: missing a comma on meta tag in content attribute for user scalable

Comment: You need to also close the link tag for mobile.

Comment: is the actual code missing the closing > on your mobile stylesheet?

Comment: Since you have media query inside of your mobile css, calling the file will suffice `<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: If you are trying the code on IE8, It will not work unless you add html5shiv and respond.js

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing `@media (max-width: 480px)` etc.

Comment: 320 is too small actually. The official size is 380px. It wont do so for tablets. But if smartphones is all you are worried about, then 380px it is.

Comment: I didn't mean the size, I meant the declaration.  You're right, no phone is smaller than 320px.  I've changed my example.

Comment: Also, to reduce the number of file requests, I always keep my responsive CSS at the bottom of my main CSS file.  Then, for production, I minify the file.  Smaller files, and less requests = faster loading on mobile!

Answer (score 0):

Making a site responsive is no simple task, if you want to do it properly.
I would stick to frameworks like bootstrap i.E. 
That way you can safe yourself a lot of headache.